# What are golf cups made of?

Tags: equipment, golf

I have two young nieces who like to play with the putting green equipment in their back yard.  I want to make sure that they're not handling anything nasty, and in particular I want to ensure that the metal bases of the flags aren't made of lead or some other harmful metal.  What are golf cups made of?

Comment: I suspect this varies based on the particular variety/model.  Do you know that information?

Answer (score 2):

Cheap ones are made of plastic.  These would not normally be found at courses because they would crack, chip, and wear out (the flag is the biggest problem).  Most decent courses use aluminum cups like [this](https://www.standardgolf.com/cups/item/aluminum-cup-2-2.html).

Comment: Actually I've never seen a metal cup to date, and I've played on some pretty nice courses so it's not a money thing. Plastic is actually more durable for the kind of abuse these cups take, which is more about the constant insertion and removal of the flagstick which will bend and ding up an aluminum base.